# eee pc 1000h wlan not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lubuntu, eeepc

I have a eee pc 1000h with lubuntu 14.04 on it (migrating from windows xp). wlan is not working, even if with lspci it detects the wlan card (01:00.0 network controller : Ralink corp. RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1t/2R PCIe). I'm new to linux. Any troubleshooting will help, thanks in advance for time and help.

Comment: what is the output of `rfkill list all` ?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your Wireless is turned on (Fn+F2 will toggle it on and off).  Next there is a Ubuntu Community Help Wiki here 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide
that will walk you through the troubleshooting process.